# Android Studio: is there a shortcut to extract Kotlin standard functions?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, shortcut

Say i want to use .apply{}:

```
//Without using apply
user.name
user.address
user.age

//With apply
user.apply { 
    name
    address
    age
}
```

like [extract variable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-variable.html) (ctrl-alt-v) searches the current code to replace every iteration with a variable, i'd like something that given an expression, wraps all the iterations in an apply{}, or any other standard Kotlin function like Let or Run.

Is it possible in current android studio (3.2) ?